# How to calculate value of column in dataframe based on value/count of other columns in the dataframe in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which has data of 24 hours of the day for a whole month with the following fields:

```
(df1):- date,hour,mid,rid,percentage,total
```

I need to create  2nd dataframe using this dataframe with the following fields:

```
(df2) :-  date, hour,mid,rid,hour_total
```

Here hour_total is to be calculated as below:

If for a combination of (date,mid,rid) from dataframe 1, count of records where df1.percentage is 0 is 24, then hour_total = df1.total/24 else hour_total = (df1.percentage /100) * total

For example if dataframe 1 is as below:- (count of records for group of date mid,rid where perc is 0 is 24)

```
 date,hour,mid,rid,perc,total

 2019-10-31,0,2, 0,0,3170.87             
 2019-10-31,1,2,0,0,3170.87             
 2019-10-31,2,2,0,0,3170.87             
 2019-10-31,3,2,0,0,3170.87             
 2019-10-31,4,2,0,0,3170.87    
.

.


2019-10-31,23,2,0,0,3170.87
```

Then dataframe 2 should be: (hour_total = df1.total/24)

```
 date,hour,mid,rid,hour_total

 2019-10-31,0,2,0,132.12             
 2019-10-31,1,4,0,132.12             
 2019-10-31,2,13,0,132.12             
 2019-10-31,3,17,0,132.12             
 2019-10-31,4,7,0,132.12    
.

.

2019-10-31,23,27,0,132.12
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the apply function

For example

```
a = np.random.randint(100,200, size=5)
b = np.random.randint(100,200, size=5)
c = [datetime.now() for x in range(100) if x%20 ==  0]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Time' : c, "A" : a, "B" : b})
```

Above data frame looks like this

```
    Time    A   B
0   2019-10-24 20:37:38.907058  158 190
1   2019-10-24 20:37:38.907058  161 127
2   2019-10-24 20:37:38.908056  100 100
3   2019-10-24 20:37:38.908056  163 164
4   2019-10-24 20:37:38.908056  121 159
```

Now if we want to compute a new column whose value depends on the other values of column. 
You can define a function which does this computation.

```
def func(x):
    t = x[0] # time
    a = x[1] # A
    b = x[2] # B
    return a+b
```

And apply this function to the data frame

```
df1["new_col"] = df1.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Which would yield the following result.

```
Time    A   B   new_col
0   2019-10-24 20:37:38.907058  158 190 348
1   2019-10-24 20:37:38.907058  161 127 288
2   2019-10-24 20:37:38.908056  100 100 200
3   2019-10-24 20:37:38.908056  163 164 327
4   2019-10-24 20:37:38.908056  121 159 280
```